# Extracting data from JSON returned undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm new to javascript and JSON. I have JSON like this:

```
data = [[{"checked":false,"no":"1"},{"checked":true,"no":"2"}]]
```

But I am having a hard time looping through just to get the "checked" value.

I used for loop then i try to console.log data.checked but it always returned undefined. How can do this?

Comment: This is not JSON!

Comment: because you get checked of array, remove one pair of brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get first array element using index and use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method for iterating.

```js
var data = [
  [{
    "checked": false,
    "no": "1"
  }, {
    "checked": true,
    "no": "2"
  }]
];

data[0].forEach(function(v) {
  console.log(v.checked);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a nested array, so to access the `checked` property of the member objects you'll need to access them at `data[0]`.

```
let innerData = data[0];
for(let i = 0; i < innerData.length; i++) {  
  console.log(innerData[i].checked);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your JSON, your have a top-level array, then inside that you have another level of array(s), and in that array you have the objects. So what you should do is something like this.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
  for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; ++j) {
    console.log(data[i][j], data[i][j].checked);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get rid of the double nested array with

```
array = array[0];
```

Then loop as you always loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
 // This is array in array with object 
var data = [[{"checked":false,"no":"1"},{"checked":true,"no":"2"}]]


for(var  i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++){ // Test the length of first array and go inside
    for(var  z = 0 ; z < data[i].length ; z++){ // When you are inside the array go to another one array and inside go and search 'chacked'
        console.log(data[i][z]['checked']); // show value of the checked
    }
}
```